# How to compute this improper integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

> Let $n\geq1$ be an integer and let
>
> $$I_n=\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{\arctan x}{(1+x^2)^n} \,\mathrm dx$$
>
> Prove that
>
> $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\dfrac{I_n}{n}=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6} \tag{1}$$
>
> $$\int\limits_{0}^{\infty} \arctan x\cdot\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{x^2}\right) \,\mathrm d x=\dfrac{\pi^2}{6} \tag{2}$$

I have an idea that dominated convergence theorem may help here. But I am not getting the proper way.

Comment: i have just learned about Residues so i would use them to calculate $I_n$, but dont listen to me. Based on first identity we expect  $I_n=1/n$

Comment: @MilanStojanovic Unfortunately, $I_1=\left[\frac12\arctan^2x\right]_0^\infty=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the monotone convergence theorem to show that the series and the integral are equal:
\begin{align} 
\sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{I_n}{n} &\stackrel{\text{MCT}}{=} \int \limits_0^\infty \arctan(x) \sum \limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n (1+x^2)^n} \, \mathrm{d} x  = \int \limits_0^\infty \arctan(x) \left[-\ln\left(1 - \frac{1}{1+x^2}\right)\right] \, \mathrm{d} x  \\
&\hspace{5pt}= \int \limits_0^\infty \arctan(x) \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right) \, \mathrm{d} x \, .
\end{align}
The integral can be evaluated by integrating by parts:
\begin{align}
\int \limits_0^\infty \arctan(x) \ln \left(1 + \frac{1}{x^2}\right) \, \mathrm{d} x &= \int \limits_0^\infty \left[\frac{2 \arctan{x}}{1+x^2} - \frac{\ln(1+x^2)}{x (1+x^2)}\right] \, \mathrm{d} x \\
&\hspace{-11pt}\stackrel{x = \sqrt{\mathrm{e}^t - 1}}{=} \frac{\pi^2}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \int \limits_0^\infty \frac{t}{\mathrm{e}^t - 1} \, \mathrm{d} t \\
&= \frac{\pi^2}{4} - \frac{1}{2} \zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{4} - \frac{\pi^2}{12} = \frac{\pi^2}{6} \, ,
\end{align}
The integral over $t$ is found using the geometric series and, once again, the monotone convergence theorem. I have not managed to evaluate the sum directly, however.

Comment: In case the parts step isn't clear to anyone, take $u=x\arctan x-\frac12\ln(1+x^2),\,v=\ln(1+\frac{1}{x^2})$ so for small $x>0$ we have $u\approx-\frac{1}{12} x^4,\,v\approx -2\ln x$, while as $x\to\infty$ we have $u\approx\frac{\pi x}{2},\,v\approx\frac{1}{x^2}$ so the boundary term vanishes.

Comment: Did you mean to use $\log$ in one place and $\ln$ everywhere else?

Comment: @J.G. Thank you, I should have explained that in more detail.

Comment: @ChaseRyanTaylor No, I did not. Fixed it, thanks!